# Scala/Spark - Create Dataset with one column from another Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a Dataset with only one column from Case Class.

Below is the code:

```
case class vectorData(value: Array[String], vectors: Vector)


def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("Hello world!")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    //blah blah and read data etc. 
    val word2vec = new Word2Vec()
        .setInputCol("value").setOutputCol("vectors")
        .setVectorSize(5).setMinCount(0).setWindowSize(5)
    val dataset = spark.createDataset(data)

    val model = word2vec.fit(dataset)


    val encoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[vectorData]
    val result = model.transform(dataset).as(encoder)

    //val output: Dataset[Vector]  = ???
}
```

As shown in last line of the code, I want the output to be only the 2nd column which has `Vector` type with `vectors` data.

I tried with:

```
val output = result.map(o => o.vectors)
```

But this line highlighted error `No implicit arguments of type: Encoder[Vector]`

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you try result.select("vectors")?

Comment: @Prateek ```result.select("vectors")``` creates a ```sql.DataFrame```, but not ```Dataset[Vector]```. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think line:

```
implicit val vectorEncoder: Encoder[Vector] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.product[Vector]
```

should make

```
val output = result.map(o => o.vectors)
```

correct